# Boss is getting my emails in sync withn mine

Tags: email, security, clone

I recently took some time off due to medical condition, My boss has been receiving all my emails and often replies to my clients on my behalf and calls me regarding some of the mail received. I feel quite intimidated I have tried everything on outlook but still he can receive the same emails I get exactly when I receive these. Is there any way I can prevent this please HELP !!!!
Michael

Comment: Probably not.  I can open lots of mailboxes as an admin.

Comment: Speak to him. Use that email only for business.

Answer (score 3):

Your boss requested that the email server administrator forward your emails to him while you were off sick.  This would be set up on the email server, not in outlook.

You simply need to ask him to request that this forwarding is turned off, and state your reasons why.

If he says no, then there is nothing to be done.